# Convert from Mat to Point2f or Point3f

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 4 x 1 or 3 x 1 Mat variable representing a homogeneous or inhomogeneous point. I want to convert this Mat variable into type Point2f or Point3f depending on whether it's homogeneous or inhomogeneous.

For example if

```
Mat point = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 6, 4, 2);
```

If this is a homogenous representation, then the converted point is of type Point2f, and

```
Point2f pt;
pt.x = 6 / 2; pt.y = 4 / 2;
```

If this is not a homogeneous representation, then the converted point is of type Point3f, and

```
Point3f pt;
pt.x = 6; pt.y = 4; pt.z = 2;
```

Below is my current code, my call of the method is

```
Point3f pt_3d = mat2pt<Point3f>(point, 0);
Point2f pt_2d = mat2pt<Point2f>(point, 1);
```

the bug is `no viable conversion from Point3f to Point2f` and `no viable conversion from Point2f to Point3f`

```
template<typename T>
T mat2pt(Mat mat, int t = 0)
{        
    if(t == 1) // homogeneous => inhomogeneous
    {
        if(mat.size() == Size(3, 1))
        {
            pt.x = mat.at<float>(0) / mat.at<float>(2);
            pt.y = mat.at<float>(1) / mat.at<float>(2);
            return pt;
        }
        else if(mat.size() == Size(4, 1))
        {
            Point3f pt;
            pt.x = mat.at<float>(0) / mat.at<float>(3);
            pt.y = mat.at<float>(1) / mat.at<float>(3);
            pt.z = mat.at<float>(2) / mat.at<float>(3);
            return pt;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "incorrect Mat size" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    else if(t == 0)
    {
        if(mat.size() == Size(2, 1))
        {
            Point2f pt;
            pt.x = mat.at<float>(0);
            pt.y = mat.at<float>(1);
            return pt;
        }
        else if(mat.size() == Size(3, 1))
        {
            Point3f pt;
            pt.x = mat.at<float>(0);
            pt.y = mat.at<float>(1);
            pt.z = mat.at<float>(2);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "incorrect Mat size" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "invalid value for parameter t" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use two separate functions

Comment: You can't determine returning type at runtime, it contradicts the idea of templates. I would use Point3f for both or you could create wrapper class for Point and use polymorphism (return pointer to class Point, which is interface for Point2f and Point3f). Or just create a single wrapper class for point which holds information about homogeneity.